# Linear algebra object unclear in the theory behind PCA

Tags: vectors, inner-products

Basic issue but one that created a moment of reflection for me. In studying PCA we use the unit vector $\vec{w}_{1}$ and reproject all observations $\vec{x}_{n}$ onto this via the formula:

$\vec{w}_{1}^{T} \cdot \vec{x}_n{}$

Normally the result of the product between these two elements should be a scalar but from the [page](https://towardsdatascience.com/principal-component-analysis-part-1-the-different-formulations-6508f63a5553) where this example was taken it would appear to be a vector. I'm probably missing something.

[image]

Comment: This scalar quantity, in this context, can be thought of as a 1-dimensional vector. More generally, PCA projects the data onto some relatively low number of dimensions

Comment: Right!!! thanks. But now a doubt occurs to me. In the case of dimensionality D > 1, does the same Inner product always apply?

Comment: For a higher dimension, the dot products of $x$ with the principal components $w_1,w_2,\dots , w_D$ are combined into a vector. This vector is the “projection” of the data into a D-dimensional space.